# How to get selected value of a dropdown?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to get the the selected value of dropdown but my code does not work.

Here [`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/d4kkg/10/)

**View**

```
<select style="height: 26px;" data-bind="options: StateTitle, 
        event: { change: ddlState }, optionsText: 'StateText', 
        optionsValue: 'StateId', value: selectedState, 
        optionsCaption: 'Choose State.....'"></select>
```

**ViewModel**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
   self.StateTitle = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedState = ko.observable();
    var data = {
        StateId:1,
        StateText:'Demo'

    }
    self.StateTitle(data);

      self.ddlState = function (newValue) {
        alert("State Id " + ko.toJSON(newValue.StateId));
    }
}

  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over complicating it with your change event. You can just reference the observable that you have: `selectedState`, which your `select` passes the value of `StateId` to when it changes:

### [Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4kkg/13/)

**Markup:**

```
<select style="height: 26px;" 
        data-bind="options: StateTitle, 
                   optionsText: 'StateText', 
                   optionsValue: 'StateId', 
                   value: selectedState, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose State.....'">
</select>

<p data-bind="text: selectedState"></p>
```

**Knockout**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.StateTitle = ko.observableArray([{
        'StateId': 1,
        'StateText': 'Demo'
    }, {
        'StateId': 2,
        'StateText': 'Another'
    }]);
    self.selectedState = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

To create an alert, simply subscribe to the observable:

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4kkg/15/)

```
self.selectedState.subscribe(function(item) {
    alert('Selected State Id:' + item);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: Where does that error show? in the fiddle or your code?

Comment: @Subhash did you place the `subscribe` function after the declaration of `self.selectedState`? If you write the subscribe function before you have declared and setup the observable, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
   self.StateTitle = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedState = ko.observable();
    var data = {
        StateId:1,
        StateText:'Demo'

    }
    self.StateTitle.push(data);

      self.ddlState = function () {
        alert("State Id " + self.selectedState().StateId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedState is not defined

Comment: Edited answer ,it shd have been self.selectedState().StateId  ,self. is important,now try, mark as answer if it works.

Comment: Now it show: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'StateId' of undefined

Comment: Please try it in fiddle first

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe  `selectedState` like this:

```
self.selectedState.subscribe(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Now this will track the `StateId` when the drop-down selection is changed.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/9WMjR/1/)

Comment: It show this error my Page "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Comment: there is some mistak you are doing due to which you are seeing error, its working in fiddle so it should be working on your page

Comment: where have you placed it?

Comment: ordering and placement matters it should be at the place where i have placed in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add a little check, http://jsfiddle.net/29u4X/

```
self.selectedState.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    //check if nothing is been selected
    if (typeof (newValue) === 'undefined' || newValue === '') {
        return;
    }
    //Do want ever you want to do
    alert(newValue);
});
```